How do I get bash completion for nested makefiles in ZSH on MacOS?
I've made use of Zsh's native completion approach, and that has been having odd performance issues when tab completing makefiles that have not changed.
Instead, I'd like to use bash completion in make.
I've discovered you can easily enable bash completion in make by placing the following line in the zsh profile:
compinit
bashcompinit

However, unlike in normal bash (modern, on latest releases of Linux, e.g. RHel/Debian), the bash-completion available in mac does not expose any imported makefile targets:
# mk/foo.mk
foo:
  echo bar

# makefile
include mk/foo.mk

# shell 
$: make <tab><tab>
.... (nothing)

I'd expect a full report of all of the phony targets I've defined in my included makefile in bash.  Is there some extra tinkering I must do when using bash-completion from zsh?

Use a newer bash version from brew.

And do not forget to install one of the bash-completion formulae if one is not automatically installed with bash.

@DiegoTorresMilano : The OP wants to use zsh, not bash.

I'm not sure whether it is possible. While bashcompinit installs you a completion system in zsh which is supposed to be compatible, I'm not sure whether compatibility goes so far as to let you work  all of bash-completion as well. I would try to run, for comparision, a bash shell, and see whether it works from there. If it does, I fear you have to bite the bullet and debug it for zsh. You could also submit a bug report, but I doubt that the maintainer of bash-completion would be willing to test his software for the use inside zsh.

Keep in mind tha bashcompinit only provides zsh implementations of the bash completion API; it does nothing about ensuring that bash-specific code has the same semantics when executed by zsh.
